# Create dictionary with join in python

Tags: python, dictionary, join

Each row of my document contains a dictionary of informations :

```
{'O':34, 'D': 75, '2015-01':{'c':30,'f':90},'2016-01':{'c':100,'f':78,'r':90.5}}
```

The expected is :

```
{'2015-01,c':30,'2015-01,f':90,'2016-01,c':100....}
```

I tried this in python :

```
for row in cursor:
       d = dict((''.join([l,',',row[l].keys()]),row[l].values())
                     for l in row.keys - ['O','D'])
```

But I got this error :
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, dict_keys found
Any help please.
Thank you

Comment: You are only wanting to manipulate data where you have a valid four digit year? Because your expected output is ignoring the first two items in your dictionary.

Comment: I'm looking to join only for date

Comment: @idjaw Since the code contains `row.keys - ['O','D']`, I guess this is the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Efferalgan exactly I'm ignoring my other keys

Comment: Are those keys strings, and that `=`? That dictionary is invalid sysntax

Comment: Yes. The keys are strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your nesting is always one level deep, you could do following:

```
d = {'O':34, 'D': 75, '2015':{'c':30,'f':90},'2016':{'c':100,'f':78,'r':90.5}}

def join_dict(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for k2, v2 in v.items():
                yield '{},{}'.format(k, k2), v2


result = {k: v for k, v in join_dict(d)}
print(result)
# {'2016,f': 78, '2016,r': 90.5, '2016,c': 100, '2015,f': 90, '2015,c': 30}
```

Comment: Where do you ignore the other keys?

Comment: Your *date strings* have nested dicts. Using `isinstance(..., dict)` handles that.

Comment: The only thing that *could* break this is if the real data does have cases where the invalid keys have dictionaries as values. But the only person who can confirm this is the OP.

Comment: Even if it's like that : 2015-01 (year-month) ?

Comment: @MAYA Is the sample data you posted accurate? Are there cases where you do have a dictionary as value where the key is invalid?

Comment: @MAYA You should try it out

Comment: I check my data and I updated my example. Please see my post above

Comment: @MAYA rule of thumb. Please don't change the requirements of your question after people have already answered and provided valid solutions. Luckily what you changed does not change this solution and this solution is still valid and will work. But, again, in the future do not change requirements after solutions have been posted.

Comment: @idjaw sorry I checked my data and I figured out that it's not the same. Otherwise, why my solution get an error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this :

```
row = {'O':34, 'D': 75, '2015':{'c':30,'f':90},'2016':{'c':100,'f':78,'r':90.5}}
dic = {}

for key in row :
    if key != 'O' and key != 'D':
        subdic = row[key]
        for subkey in subdic :
            dic[key+","+subkey] = subdic[subkey]

print dic
```

Comment: there is other keys and it's not same for all rows, this is way I tried  
`row.keys -['O','D']`

Comment: Well I ignored the key you showed, but it can easily be completed with a list of ignored keys.

Comment: It is not a fix number. Sometimes, some keys are absent in my row